# Postgres time zones and formatting

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I know there are some similar questions about this, but I'm having a hard time understanding why my database is formatting times the way it is.

I have a field called `created_at` and in the database the value is:

```
2017-03-30 11:01:25.976-04
```

It's 11am New York time, with a four-hour negative offset from UTC.

I want it to display as **11:01am**. When I use `TO_CHAR()` to format it, though, it converts the time to UTC and shows **3:01pm**.

```
SELECT to_char(ledger.created_at, 'Mon DD YYYY HH12: MI AM') AS formatted_date ...
```

I can fix this by adding `AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'` but I don't like the idea of hard-coding that in my application.

```
SELECT to_char(ledger.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York', 'Mon DD YYYY HH12: MI AM') AS formatted_date ...
```

It seems like the timestamp field *knows* what time it is already, and what time zone it's in (or at least the offset amount) and it displays 11am in the database itself.

I also know I can `SET` the local time before each query and it will work, but again I'm wondering if there's an easier way. It seems like maybe I could strip the timezone information and just get the **11:01am** time that's in the database. If there isn't a way, I can live with it, but I needed to check.

For context, this is within a Node and Express app using Sequelize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are running into what the [configured](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) [*TimeZone*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) for the server is. If that is the case, and you can't change it, your best option is to set the *TimeZone* for the current session using `SET TIME ZONE '...';`

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to figure out from the documentation: is this something set in postgresql.conf or does it inherit whatever my server is set to?

Comment: I believe the order is: inherit server timezone, value defined in postgresql.conf, `SET SESSION TIME ZONE ...`, finally `SET LOCAL TIME ZONE ...`.

Meaning that if you don't specify a `LOCAL TIME ZONE` it will look for ` SESSION TIME ZONE`. If neither of those have been defined, it will fall back to the value defined in `postgresql.conf`. If there isn't a value defined there, it will use whatever your server timezone is.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't store the time zone, it stores `timestamp with time zone` as UTC timestamp.

Upon retrieval it is converted to the time zone in effect in the database session (set with `SET TimeZone = '...'`).

So to convert it to a string at a certain time zone, there are two ways:

- Adjust the session time zone with `SET TimeZone = '...'`.
- Explicitly specify the time zone with `AT TIME ZONE`.

From your question I deduce that your session time zone is set to UTC.

You *have* to specify the desired time zone somewhere...

Comment: Thank you. To make sure I understand, when you say the "TimeZone configuration parameter", are you talking about something that is set globally over multiple sessions in a config file somewhere? Or are you referring to using `SET TimeZone` ? Thanks for your patience.